# Does Shared instance variable require atomic-operations in multiple threads? (Thread-Safety)

Tags: ruby, concurrency, atomic

Is the below code thread-safe?

```
@total_count = 0
t = []
100.times do
  t << Thread.new do
    100.times do
       @total_count += 2
    end
  end
end
t.map(&:join)
p @total_count
```

It seems to work, but how come you don't need to implement atomic operations as all the threads are writing to the same instance variable. Are instance variables in Ruby atomically implemented with atomic operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the code is not thread-safe. It only has the appearance of being so in certain Ruby interpreters (e.g. Ruby 2.0 (MRI/KRI)), because of the effect of the GIL/GVL (Global Interpreter Lock/Global VM Lock). In such cases, it will likely yield the result you expect (`20000`)—but the approach in general does not guarantee safety.

Running the code in the JRuby interpreter, which does not have the GIL and runs threads in true parallel, gives different results on different runs, e.g.:

```
jruby-1.7.6 :011 > p @total_count
16174
 => 16174
```

The `@total_count += 2` expands to `@total_count = @total_count + 2`, meaning threads can interleave between the RHS read and the LHS write. This means the total could (and will often) be less (but in this case, not more) than the total expected. The code can be made thread-safe through the use of a `Mutex`:

```
@mutex = Mutex.new
@total_count = 0
t = []
100.times do
  t << Thread.new do
    100.times do
      @mutex.synchronize do
        @total_count += 2
      end
    end
  end
end
t.map(&:join)
p @total_count
```

In JRuby, that then always yields the expected result:

```
jruby-1.7.6 :014 > p @total_count
20000
 => 20000
```

I realise it's not the same as your question (which I understand to be about whether `+=` is atomic), but the principle can be demonstrated even in Ruby 2.0 (MRI/KRI) by expanding the assignment and inserting a small sleep:

```
@total_count = 0
t = []
100.times do
  t << Thread.new do
    100.times do
      total_count = @total_count
      sleep 0.0000001
      @total_count = total_count + 2
    end
  end
end
t.map(&:join)
p @total_count
```

In Ruby 2.0, one possible run yields:

```
2.0.0p247 :013 >     p @total_count
512
 => 512
```

Using a `Mutex`, however:

```
@mutex = Mutex.new
@total_count = 0
t = []
100.times do
  t << Thread.new do
    100.times do
      @mutex.synchronize do
        total_count = @total_count
        sleep 0.0000001
        @total_count = total_count + 2
      end
    end
  end
end
t.map(&:join)
p @total_count
```

yields the correct result:

```
2.0.0p247 :224 > p @total_count
20000
 => 20000
```